# Simple question about $G$-module definition

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, definition, group-homomorphism, general-linear-group

This may be a too simple question, but I am new to this representation theory stuff and just want to be clear.

In the Bruce E. Sagan "The Symmetric Group: Representations, Combinatorial Algorithms, and Symmetric Functions", Definition 1.3.1 says that a vector space $V$ is a $G$-module (where $G$ is a given group) if there is a group homomorphism $\rho:G\rightarrow GL(V)$.

My question is: Does not that mean every vector space $V$ is automatically a $G$-module via the trivial homomorphism? Or should the definition be using the word "nontrivial"?

I might be missing something here and having a brain lag. I have read the previous section, but I am pretty sure it is presented differently in wording, defining that "A matrix representation of a group $G$ is a group homomorphism from $G$ to $GL_d$".

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Yes, every vector space is a $G$-module with trivial action. Every vector space is a Lie algebra with trivial product. Every real vector space is a real manifold, etc.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I mean, this is just the first time I see a definition like this. Usually, when I see a (basic) definition in math text book like "An object satisfies property A if ...", then I am sure the definition is interesting and I can find objects that are not satisfying A. For example, "Every ring is a module (over itself)", but it is clear what does not classify as module. Here, it's like saying "We define a ring to be good if it satisfies property B", when clearly every ring satisfies B. Hence maybe that's why the word "nontrivial" is missing in my question. What do u think sir?

Comment: The reason this is confusing is that the given definition is not very clear. The point is that being a $G$-module means we specify such a homomorphism, and when we speak of a $G$-module, that homomorphism is then part of the "data". So really the $G$-module is the pair $(V,\rho)$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes. I think yours is clearer, sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wording of the definition seems to imply that we only care whether the homomorphism exists, and if it does then we forget about the homomorphism and call the vector space a $G$-module. This does not tell the whole story. Even though every vector space is a $G$-module with the trivial homomorphism, this fact is not really of much importance. We actually care what the homomorphism specifically *is*, and the homomorphism should really be included in the definition of the module.

Comment: Yes. I know about the importance, bu also I really agree yours should be added for clarity. Thank you.